# resizing text responsively with Susy

Tags: responsive-design, susy-compass

I'm just getting started with Susy and I'm running into a few problems, and I can't seem to find a decent answer after a few hours of Googling.

From what I know, Susy uses ems to configure the columns. My problem comes in when I want to resize my text.

Specifically speaking, I'm using rems in my layout, and I have to set the following:

```
html {
    font-size: 125%; // for 20px base font size
}
```

On a smaller viewport, I would like to resize my body text to 16px.

```
html {
    font-size: 100%; // resizes to 16px
}
```

**The problem is, why I do it in this manner, values inserted into the grids change, and everything gets narrower.**

I'm using rems for top and bottom paddings and I'm envisioning using susy for left and right paddings. This means to say if I change the font sizes, the whole page goes haywire because grids suddenly get extremely narrow.

I trust that there is a way to resolve this problem, but I seem to be totally stuck without any ideas here. Or maybe I'm approaching responsive design in susy in a wrong way?

Help is extremely appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either stop your container element from resizing, or you can just use more columns in the mobile view.

Susy will build grids using any unit you want. You have complete control of the settings. In fact, the actual grids themselves are usually built with `%` units internally — only the container has other units applied to it. If you override the container size, either manually or using the `$container-width` setting, the columns will adjust to fill the container. For small screens you could set the container width to be 100%, and then use the default susy width on larger screens.

Comment: Can I know how can I stop the container element from resizing if I were to change the font size under html? I mean i would want to control the size of the outer container element since its given a max width depending on the font size in rems. If I switch the font size, wouldn't everything change then? Thanks for the help @Eric!

Comment: Yes, if you use rem to size your grid, then the grid will change when you change the font size. I'm not sure why that's a problem. If you don't want the grid to respond to font sizes, then use a different unit for the grid. If you do want it to respond to font sizes, then you need adjust to the different root font sizes you are setting. The choice is yours.